# iOS: Increase animation by click a button

Tags: ios, animation, swift4, cabasicanimation

I have the following animation, I need to implement a code, by clicking on a button the animation increased by one until a value that I want to reach it.

I try the following code:

```
    let strokeIt = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    let timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        drawBgShape()
        drawTimeLeftShape()
      }


func drawBgShape() {
    bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX , y: view.frame.midY), radius:
        100, startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    bgShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
    view.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)
}

func drawTimeLeftShape() {
    timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX , y: view.frame.midY), radius:
        100, startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
    timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
    view.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)
}
```

and when click a button :

```
     var x = 0.0
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {

        strokeIt.fromValue = x
        strokeIt.toValue = x + 0.1

        strokeIt.duration = 0.25
        timeLeftShapeLayer.add(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
        x = x + 0.1
}
```

How can I achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an explicit animation to achieve this.

For some properties of `CALayer`, Core Animation will add an *implicit* animation *for* you. The `strokeEnd` property is one of these.

This means that Core Animation will *automatically* animate any changes to a layer's `strokeEnd` property. You don't need to create an animation object and add it yourself.

There are a few things you'll need to amend with your implementation to get it working.

1) The background circle, to look like the image you've posted, should have a grey `strokeColor` within your `drawBgShape` function:

```
bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

2) The `strokeEnd` for `timeLeftShapeLayer` should be set to `0.0` as its starting value within your `drawTimeLeftShape` function.

```
 timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
```

3) Remove the `strokeIt` animation property from your class, you don't need it.

4) Update your `click` function to slowly increment the `strokeEnd` property of `timeLeftShapeLayer` directly. This is one simple line of code:

```
timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd += 0.1
```

Here's an example implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        drawBgShape()
        drawTimeLeftShape()
    }

    func drawBgShape() {
        bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX , y: view.frame.midY),
            radius: 100,
            startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians,
            endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians,
            clockwise: true
        ).cgPath
        bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        view.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)
    }

    func drawTimeLeftShape() {
        timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX , y: view.frame.midY),
            radius: 100,
            startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians,
            endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians,
            clockwise: true
        ).cgPath
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        view.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)
    }

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd += 0.1
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's worked, but how to set max and min value of animation?

Comment: You’re welcome. Not sure what you mean - are you talking about from and to values? If you could amend your question to explain the functionality you’re looking for it would help understand.

Comment: Thanks, I reached what I need.
I want to set the stop value (max numbers of clicking)
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd += 1/34
        if  timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd == 1        {
            timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        }
    }